# Going back few activities without destroying the bottom one

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, kotlin, android-lifecycle

I did a simple sample with 3 activities:

1. `ActivityA`
2. `ActivityB`
3. `ActivityC`

There is just one button on each of them.

- Button on `ActivityA` opens `ActivityB`

  ```
      val intent = Intent(this, ActivityB::class.java)
      startActivity(intent)
  ```
- Button on `ActivityB` opens `ActivityC`

  ```
      val intent = Intent(this, ActivityC::class.java)
      startActivity(intent)
  ```
- Button on `ActivityC` is supposed to go back to `ActivityA` but killing of ActivityB in the process

  ```
      val intent = Intent(this, ActivityA::class.java)
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)
      startActivity(intent)
  ```

**It does what I want and the whole flow looks like this when logged:**

```
ActivityA onCreate()
ActivityA button clicked
ActivityB onCreate()
ActivityB button clicked
ActivityC onCreate()
ActivityC button clicked
ActivityB onDestroy()
ActivityA onDestroy()
ActivityA onCreate()
ActivityC onDestroy()
```

The problem with this solution is the fact that `ActivityA` gets recreated (destroy and create). **Is there a way to just resume it instead?**

**Disclaimer:**
This is, of course just a simplified case. Because of the several reasons in my app I'd rather avoid using `onActivityResult()` and `finish()` on click approaches. I need to preserve proper back button behaviour.

Comment: when B goes to C use finish(); when C goes to A use finish(); after calling Intent

Comment: I can't do it like this for many reasons. This is just simplified case

Comment: can you tell me any one reason?

Comment: @AbhinavGupta Simple - I don't want to kill off every single activity on the way on every case. There are some special cases I need to go back like this. Your solution totally brakes back/up button behaviour.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(C.this, A.class); 
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(intent);

Comment: use android:launchMode="singletask" in activity tag in manifeast

Comment: @SandeepParish try his solution you can try that tooo :)

Comment: From my experience, setting android:launchMode="singletask" is asking for trouble :/ It seems to be doing the work tho. I wish there were a proper flags combination for this

Comment: You really should go through android docs, these are the very basics things, anyway use singleTop or singleInstance (as per req) and override onNewIntent(..) in your Activity A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it almost right. What you're missing (to avoid activity recreate) is a `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` flag.

```
val intent = Intent(this, ActivityA::class.java)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
startActivity(intent)
```

More about it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)